# É possível utilizar SCRUM em projeto de escopo fechado?

Tags: scrum

Gostaria de saber qual a opinião de vocês e experiência sobre o uso do framework  **SCRUM** em um projeto de escopo fechado.

É possível e faz sentido ?

Imagino que o recomendado seria mudar a forma de condução do projeto para a metodologia ágil,  e **garantir entregas de maior valor**, mas existem situações que é difícil quando o cliente não que mudar sua cultura.

Comment: Não vejo porque não, você fecha o escopo e aí gerencia o projeto como partes, no fim tudo tem que encaixar no que foi fechado. Se dá certo eu não sei, algumas pessoas, aquelas que apelidaram isso de *screw up*, diriam que nunca dá, mas como o escopo está aberto ninguém percebe, afinal se você não sabe onde quer chegar, de que jeito, quanto tempo vai levar, quanto vai custar, seja lá o que acontecer, desde que se chegue e seja minimamente agradável, está bom. Eu adoro escopo aberto, mas entendo o cliente que não adora. Raramente vejo essas metodologias entregarem mais valor.

Comment: O que entrega valor é competência técnica e isso passa pela pessoa não acreditar em metodologias mágicas que fazem tudo funcionar bem. Metodologias são úteis, mas não são mágicas, muitas pessoas acreditam nisso, até porque são aprendidas em pregações.

Comment: O que deixa complicado também é tal da data parede! É o que vejo normalmente o "dividir para conquistar".

Answer (score 1):

Já trabalhei em projetos sem escopo/âmbito, utilizando a framework SCRUM.
O importante é seguir a metodologia e todos usarem o mesmo vocabulário.
Seguirem os valores, papeis, eventos artefactos e regras do scrum.
O facto de existir um escopo/âmbito serve para ser orçamentada uma data de entrega desse escopo/âmbito.
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: De fato o escopo fechado facilita a questão orçamentaria. Mas será que existe alguma estratégia/um passo a passo ou um guide que mostra pontos para conseguir encaixar o scrum neste tipo de projeto ? Talvez alguém aqui já tenha passado por este problema. 
PS: Ainda não consigo marcar que gostei de tua resposta porque não tenho reputação alta aqui no stackoverflow